# How do I parse a data URL in Node?

Tags: node.js, url, base64

I've got a data URL like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...
```

What's the easiest way to get this as binary data (say, a `Buffer`) so I can write it to a file?

Comment: It’s not a URL. It’s a URI. A data URI.

Comment: @КонстантинВан You can argue with MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: @a paid nerd Looking up in [the RFC doc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2397), turned out it’s a _data URL_. Sorry for my misinformation. But just saying, [don’t trust MDN too much](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51406819/4510033).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Put the data into a Buffer using the 'base64' encoding, then write this to a file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var string = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
var regex = /^data:.+\/(.+);base64,(.*)$/;

var matches = string.match(regex);
var ext = matches[1];
var data = matches[2];
var buffer = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
fs.writeFileSync('data.' + ext, buffer);
```

Comment: Substitute the appropriate file extension? This is just an example, the general solution is: (1) get the data part after the `data:whatever/whatever;base64,` part, (2) put it into a Buffer using 'base64', (3) write this to a file. If the mime type is different, use a different file extension/use a regex/etc.

Comment: How about `var data = string.substr(string.indexOf('base64') + 7)` ?

Comment: RegEx on a large data URI is very CPU Intensive/slow. Best avoided.

Comment: While this approach works there can be a very large performance hit from the regex. On my machine it was about 192X slower with the regex than using splits (about 5200ms instead of 27ms). So if your data URL represents reasonably sized images (~300KB), this barely works.

Comment: Then just apply the regex to the first 268 bytes to extract the mime type. The maximum length of a mime type is 255 bytes. Use split bert's answer to extract the data.

Comment: Or maybe try taking out the $ from the regex?

Comment: This is way too slow. Using splits is much better.

Comment: The data content of a data URI may be **not** in base64. Can it handle `data:,`, which is a totally valid _data URI_?

Comment: Really really slow - don't use this solution.

Answer (score 38):

Try this

```
const dataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
const buffer = Buffer.from(dataUrl.split(",")[1], 'base64');
```

Comment: Seems like that approach is deprecated now. I had to use this instead: `buffer = Buffer.from(dataUrl.split(",")[1], 'base64')`

Answer (score 6):

I was looking into the sources of Node.js and stumbled upon [this code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/df22736d80588e04550cbb65a421a74dae661676/lib/internal/modules/esm/get_source.js#L31-L36) that decodes a data URL into a `Buffer`. Although the function is not public and exclusively intended to parse encoded ES modules, it sheds light on aspects of data URLs that are apparently not considered by some other answers: the content of data URLs **must not be base64 encoded** and **may be URL encoded**, and it may even be unencoded.

Essentially, the Node.js logic boils down to something like the code below plus error handling:

```js
const parsed = new URL(url);
const match = /^[^/]+\/[^,;]+(?:[^,]*?)(;base64)?,([\s\S]*)$/.exec(parsed.pathname);
const { 1: base64, 2: body } = match;
const buffer = Buffer.from(decodeURIComponent(body), base64 ? 'base64' : 'utf8');
```

This will correctly handle different encodings of a Javascript file with the content `console.log("Node.js");`:

- data:text/javascript,console.log("Node.js");
- data:text/javascript,console.log(%22Node.js%22)%3B
- data:text/javascript;base64,Y29uc29sZS5sb2coIk5vZGUuanMiKTs=

The resulting buffer can be converted into a string if required with `buffer.toString()`.

Answer (score 3):

I also met such questions (parsing and validating data URL) recently and found the following workaround: https://gist.github.com/bgrins/6194623

I created 2 packages to make working with data URL easier in the code. Here they are:
https://github.com/killmenot/valid-data-url
https://github.com/killmenot/parse-data-url

Check out [examples](https://github.com/killmenot/parse-data-url#example)

Answer (score 1):

This method works for me

```js
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
  var data = dataURI.split(',')[1]; 
  var byteString = Buffer.from(data, "base64");

  // separate out the mime component
  var mimeString = dataURI.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];

  // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
  var blob = new Blob([byteString], { type: mimeString  });
  return blob;
}
```

to use

```js
var uri = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='; 
dataURItoBlob(uri)
```