# FileReader.readAsDataURL upload to express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code to upload to my Node.js/Express.js backend.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

reader.onload = function (e) {
  var result = http.post('/files', e.target.result);
  result.success(function () { 
    alert('done'):
  });
}
```

My route looks like:

```
app.post('/files', function (req, res) {
  var cws = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/media/file');
  req.pipe(cws);
  res.send('success');
});
```

When I open /media/file with an image app I get a warning that it cannot read it. When I open the image file with a text-editor I see the base64 encoded string inside. Do I need to convert the string first before writing it to desk?

Comment: Which FileReader implementation are you using?

Comment: Not sure which one I am using Chrome 18. After some digging it seems the DataURL is prepended with some meta data I need to remove.

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured out as well (facing similar issue on my own). Probably a splitting followed by a base64-decode solves this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that a DataURL is prepended by meta data. You first need to remove that part before you create a base64 buffer.

```
var data_url = req.body.file;
var matches = data_url.match(/^data:.+\/(.+);base64,(.*)$/);
var ext = matches[1];
var base64_data = matches[2];
var buffer = new Buffer(base64_data, 'base64');

fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/media/file', buffer, function (err) {
  res.send('success');
});
```

Got most code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335460/how-do-i-parse-a-data-url-in-node).