# How to parse HTML/XML documents with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio, jsdom

I have an `editor.html` that contains `generatePNG` function:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Diagram</title> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script> 
//    <!-- I use many resources -->
<script></script> 

    <script> 

        function generatePNG (oViewer) { 
            var oImageOptions = { 
                includeDecoratorLayers: false, 
                replaceImageURL: true 
            }; 

            var d = new Date(); 
            var h = d.getHours(); 
            var m = d.getMinutes(); 
            var s = d.getSeconds(); 

            var sFileName = "diagram" + h.toString() + m.toString() + s.toString() + ".png"; 

            var sResultBlob = oViewer.generateImageBlob(function(sBlob) { 
                b = 64; 
                var reader = new window.FileReader(); 
                reader.readAsDataURL(sBlob); 
                reader.onloadend = function() { 
                    base64data = reader.result; 
                    var image = document.createElement('img'); 
                    image.setAttribute("id", "GraphImage"); 
                    image.src = base64data; 
                    document.body.appendChild(image); 
                } 

            }, "image/png", oImageOptions); 
            return sResult; 
        } 

    </script> 


</head> 

<body > 
    <div id="diagramContainer"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I want to access the DOM and get `image.src` using Node.js. I find that I can work with cheerio or jsdom.

I start with this:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('editor.html');
```

But I don't find how to access and get `image.src`.

Comment: The image.src you want to get is generated inside the editor.html using javascript that lays within that page?

Comment: @luiso yes the image.src is a based64 data and it is generated in the editor.html , i want to extract it from node.js server

Comment: Just to clarify, you load the editor.html into cheerio on the server? So there is no browser involved in this?

Comment: @RogierSpieker i just want to access to edtior.html from node.js and get the image.src

Comment: There are two possibilities in my mind as to what you are asking. Either you want Node.js to access an image generated by a web browser on a live page, or you want to be able to access image data stored in an html file in an img element's src attribute. Please clarify.

Comment: @JonathanGray i want to be able to access to an img element src which is generated and stored in the editor.html

Comment: @JonathanGray i have updated my code, i don't have an img tag, i just have a function which generate the image and stocked it in image.src

Comment: I just realized what you're asking and in no way did your last comment help to clarify your question. Your edit to your question on the other hand helps to clarify. Read the answer already provided. That data needs to be sent using a POST request. You can either included this data in a form to be sent to the server or you can use AJAX. Search Google on how to handle AJAX requests on the client side and then search Google on how to retrieve POST request data using Node. Alternatively you can use WebSockets, however I think you should learn the basics first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that by loading an html file into cheerio (or any other node module) will not process the HTML as a browser does. Assets (such as stylesheets, images and javascripts) will not be loaded and/or processed as they would be within a browser.

While both node.js and modern webbrowsers have the same (or similar) javascript engines, however a browser adds a lot of additional stuff, such as `window`, the `DOM` (`document`), etc. 
Node.js does not have these concepts, so there is no `window.FileReader` nor `document.createElement`.

If the image is created entirely without user interaction (your code sample 'magically' receives the `sBlob` argument wich appears to be a string like `data:<type>;<encoding>,<data>`) you could use a so called headless browser on the server, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) seems most popular these days.
Then again, if no user interaction is required for the creation of the `sBlob`, you are probably better off using a pure node.js solution, e.g. [How do I parse a data URL in Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11335500/2579117).

If there is some kind of user interaction required to create the `sBlob`, and you need to store it on a server, you can use pretty much the same solution as mentioned by simply sending the `sBlob` to the server using Ajax or a websocket, processing the `sBlob` into an image and (optionally) returning the URL where to find the image.