# Seperate out trimmed content and and original message from incoming email html

Tags: node.js, parsing, html-email, email

My server (nodejs) receives incoming email in html. Something like this

```
<div>
I am reply

<div>
On wed 20 <a href="mailto:nn@ni.com">nn@ni.com</a> wrote 
<blockquote>
This is first message
</blockquote>
</div>

</div>
```

How do I identify the content to be trimmed in that HTML ?
Any suggestions would be really helpfull

Comment: There are lots of hide/show answers - does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528085/toggle-show-hide-div-with-button

Comment: @Nathan I can do hiding and showing But I need a way to find out which content to be trimmed

Comment: Did the question change or something? I'm still not sure what you are asking. What's your purpose here, because you could 'trim' anything you want really.

Comment: @Nathan The point is how I am going to identify the content that needs to be trimmed. In the above html ```I am reply``` is original message and ```This is first message``` is the previous message that is attached to the current message. So I need to trim the previous messages from the incoming html and show only the reply. How I can achieve this

Comment: So you want `div > div` (the direct descendent of the reply div)? I'm not confident regex would be able to parse that, so you might have to consider a headless browser on the server as this answer explains: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309557/how-to-access-dom-using-node-js

Comment: @NikhilPonduri Have you achieved this?

Comment: @NikhilPonduri were you able to achieve this?

Comment: @MuhammadAbuBakr No. There is no proper way to do this. We just identified the previous message content in the incoming message and marked all the content from that DOM element of HTML as trimmed content