# How can I append file content from a folder to HTML using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, svg

I'm making a program using `Node JS` and I'm using `fs module`. I want to do something like I've a folder in which I have SVG icons.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const dir = 'icons/'

fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      files.forEach((file) => {
            if (path.extname(file) == '.svg') {
                  fs.readFile(dir + file, 'utf-8', (e, res) => {
                        if (e) throw e;
                        console.log(res);
                  });
            }
      });
});
```

So, in the above mentioned code I want to do something like, the program will check in the DOM that if any `<span></span>` tag have **classname** similar to **icon or file name** and if its true then it will read the respective file content and append it in the span tag.

For Example

> Filename = "bx bx-at.svg"

and `<span class="bx bx-at.svg"></span>` then output will be

```html
<span class="bx bx-at">
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M12,2C6.486,2,2,6.486,2,12s4.486,10,10,10c1.466,0,2.961-0.371,4.442-1.104l-0.885-1.793C14.353,19.698,13.156,20,12,20 c-4.411,0-8-3.589-8-8s3.589-8,8-8s8,3.589,8,8v1c0,0.692-0.313,2-1.5,2c-1.396,0-1.494-1.819-1.5-2V8h-2v0.025 C14.162,7.391,13.13,7,12,7c-2.757,0-5,2.243-5,5s2.243,5,5,5c1.45,0,2.748-0.631,3.662-1.621C16.186,16.269,17.07,17,18.5,17 c2.273,0,3.5-2.061,3.5-4v-1C22,6.486,17.514,2,12,2z M12,15c-1.654,0-3-1.346-3-3s1.346-3,3-3s3,1.346,3,3S13.654,15,12,15z">
    </path>
  </svg>
</span>
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/67254458/15748278