# Are angle brackets valid in data URIs?

Tags: http, url-scheme, data-uri, rfc2396

I've been reading about [Data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) which has the following example of a valid data URI:

```
data:text/html,<script>alert('hi');</script>
```

However reading through [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397#section-3) I have found the following:

```
dataurl    := "data:" [ mediatype ] [ ";base64" ] "," data
mediatype  := [ type "/" subtype ] *( ";" parameter )
data       := *urlchar
parameter  := attribute "=" value
```

> where "urlchar" is imported from [RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396)

From what I understood is that `urlchar` should be what is in [Section 2.4.3 of RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.4.3), where it notes the list of US-ASCII characters that have been excluded and specifically says:

> The angle-bracket "<" and ">" and double-quote (") characters are
> excluded because they are often used as the delimiters around URI in
> text documents and protocol fields.

So my question is, are angle brackets allowed in Data URLs? Am I misinterpreting the RFC or is the example at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is indeed wrong (in that the Data URI is invalid, although it might "work").