# How to serve base64-pdf for download from nodejs-server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I generate a PDF and get a string like `data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJf////8K...` .. I save this in a MongoDB.

Now I need to deliver this as a pdf-download to the client. So, I get the entry from the DB and try:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'});
res.end(base64String); // base64String is the data:application/pdf;base64,JVB..-string
```

This opens a empty pdf in the browser and displays a error:

> Error loading the PDF document

how can get this working? Do I need to prepare the base64String in some way before sending it to the client?

Comment: you will need to decode the base64

Comment: You probably want to decode the base64 and serve them the binary content instead. A few methods on [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11335460/243245).

Comment: @Rup that did the trick :) thank you very much